# How to change the default domain in IP address in the MobileFirstServer

Tags: mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

I am using the developer edition of IBM MFP, in my app, while building and deployment of the SQL Adapter the exception is occured like "Adapter deployment failed: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in hostname at index 10: http://XXX_XXX_008-PC:10080/", I think the '-' in the domain of IP Address is creating the exception. I have searched in the workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig directory to change the domain of the IP, but I am not able to find out where is the default configuration in the server to change the domain to localhost? I can't change the corporate domain name. So, please suggest where to change the default domain name. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, open the **Servers** view and double-click on **MobileFirst Platform Development Server** -> Change the value of "Host name".